# Cucumber exception when run the test

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests, cucumber

I have a problem that I think is silly ... 
I can't run my tests on the cucumber.

Returns the following error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: 

Classes annotated with @RunWith(Cucumber.class) must not define any
Step Definition or Hook methods. Their sole purpose is to serve as
an entry point for JUnit. Step Definitions and Hooks should be defined
in their own classes. This allows them to be reused across features.
Offending class: class Teste.testecucumber
```

Could anyone help?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 4):

@Runwith is declared in the TestRunner class of a Cucumber project. The Cucumber project has 3 defined types of classes:

1. Step Definition class
2. Feature class
3. Runner class

Please find the below examples for the above classes:

**1. Feature Class**

The test cases are written in this class

```
   Feature: Title of your feature
   I want to use this template for my feature file

   @tag1
   Scenario: Verify login to the system.
   Given I navigate to url
   And I enter username as "username"
   And I enter password as "password"
   When I click Login
   Then I should be logged into the system
```

**2. Step Definition class**

The feature steps are defined in this class

```
    public class LoginPage(){

     @Given("I navigate to the url")
     public void navigate() {

        /* your code for the above 
        step comes here*/
      }

     }
```

**3. Runner Class**

The runner class consist of the location of features and step definition. It is a Junit class and cannot contain cucumber step definition annotations. (This is the reason why runner class cannot be a step definition class). But, you can include the BeforeClass, AfterClass (Junit annotations) in this class

```
 import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
 import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
 import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @CucumberOptions( 
 features = {"classpath:<location of your folder with feature classes / package name>"},
 glue = {"<package name>" },
 tags = { "<the tags that has to be executed>","can be comma separated multiple tags" }
 )



 public class testrunner {

   //@AfterClass
   public static void quitDriver() {
    driver.quit();
   }
}
```

Hope this helps you !

Comment: `glue` should be a package name, not a directory. So `com.example.app`.

Comment: True. if its just a package in your project, you can use just the package name, if the step definitions are in a deep folder structure you can use the path to your folder. Referred from http://www.automationtestinghub.com/cucumber-test-runner-class-junit/ , https://testingneeds.wordpress.com/2015/09/15/junit-runner-with-cucumberoptions/

Comment: Since v4.2.3 it is recommended to use the package name:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/1544

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the answer as per the information